# Ignore bluetooth volume control in OS X

Tags: macos, bluetooth, sound-volume

Is there a way to ignore incoming Bluetooth sound-volume control in OS X?
And is there a way to disable outgoing volume control via Bluetooth?

Here's my situation:
I have a bluetooth speaker that has its own volume control. Every time I increase its volume, it sends a command to my Mac to increase its volume too. This is really annoying since both volumes add and volume feels like it increases exponentially.

When I connect my speaker by wire there is no problem, as I can control each volume separately.